# Kubernetes Share existing directory between pod containers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have container A with a directory like "/public/shared". Container b which is a reverse proxy running in the same pod needs access to this directory.

How can I share these? My understanding of sharing a volume is that it is either an exiting external volume/directory, or an empty directory. In this case I want to share an existing directory in container A without creating an external/additional volume.

Also, I know it is possible to adjust container A so that it copies its data on startup, or to have it expose this via a REST API. Without going into detail, I would like to avoid touching the container A image and just accomplish this with just modifying the deployment YAML. For example, via copying. But copying uses

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "cp -r /public/shared /public/mounted"]
```

And this seems to overwrite the default startup script in the pod if I understand correctly.

Comment: Typically if you're running something in Kubernetes you're in a clustered environment with multiple replicas of pods running on different nodes; sharing files at all in this environment is tricky (and Kubernetes doesn't necessarily make it easy).  Can you redesign your application to not need actual shared files but use some other storage mechanism instead?

Comment: Funny enough, after posting, I came across this blog with the exact same issue: old ruby with niginx. The blog though does not add in how to do the copying (I answered this, see below): https://www.fairwinds.com/blog/kubernetes-emptydir-not-the-same-as-dockers-volumes-from

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can add in a lifecycle command. This fixes it by copying into the empty dir without affecting the application startup. I feel like this still isn't great as it isn't guaranteed to run before startup. I guess I can also add a readiness probe to make sure these files are there. If anyone else has a better solution, I would be interested in seeing it:

```
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -r /public/shared /public/mounted"]
```